# How to put image backward on header?

Tags: wordpress, header, z-index, elementor

need some help to fix a problem. I'm trying to make some changes with image under header

[this is the image how I want to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDTkt.png)

[this is image how its currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Yxv7.jpg)

I have tried to give some z-index also from Elementor pro but still can't find solution

the link for the page where I'm working

https://tdb.pfm.mybluehost.me/rreth-nesh/

Thank you for understanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove your background of #f5f6f8 from

```
.elementor-3157 .elementor-element.elementor-element-abef236:not(.elementor-motion-effects-element-type-background), .elementor-3157 .elementor-element.elementor-element-abef236 > .elementor-motion-effects-container > .elementor-motion-effects-layer {
    /* background-color: #F5F6F8; */
}
```

add this to the body

```
  body{
        background: #F5F6F8;
  }
```

and id probs then add a margin-bottom of -30px to the header element to bring it up a bit then maybe counteract the section below with some padding top of 30px, this may not be the best way to to this but its a way

Remove the background colour #fff from the header element itself

and then on

```
#tbay-main-content{
 margin-top:-30px;
}
```

Comment: Hii Stevo, I have tried first that method, but I cant find solution, please can you give more details how to do.

Comment: I have edited the answer, this will give you the outcome you wanted

Comment: I think it will work, thank you so much for the help, have a nice day :)